# Как заставить NativeActivity загружать разные .so файлы для разных API?

Tags: java, android, c++

Пишу на C++ программу под Android. Все хорошо, но после добавления поддержки OpenGL ES3 собранную программу стало невозможно запустить на Android'ах до API18. Ок, я могу сделать две сборки .so файлов (первая будет использовать OpenGL ES, вторая - OpenGL ES3) и поместить их оба в APK, но как заставить NativeActivity загружать первый .so файл, если не удалось загрузить второй? Или существует другой способ сделать то же самое без необходимости собирать два отдельных APK файла?

Comment: Не проверял, просто предположение. Создать строковый ресурс с именем библиотеки. Создать альтернативный для API18. В манифесте в теге `<meta-data>` нашей активности указать этот ресурс в качестве значения: `android:value="@string/native_lib_name"`. Так будет подставляться имя библиотеки, в зависимости от API.

Comment: @woesss, я правильно понимаю, что ресурсы из папки res/values-v18/ будут использоваться на устройствах с API18+ и не нужно для каждого API создавать отдельную папку?

Comment: Да верно - этот квалификатор задаёт минимальную версию, а не конкретную. Только мне чудится, что где-то в доках было написано, что API18 не даёт гарантии, что на устройстве есть OpenGL ES3 или какой-либо вообще. Если такая бяка существует, то придётся либо ветвиться в нативе, либо отказаться от удобства `NativeActivity` - заменить на обычную, в ней проверять версию и наличие расширений (если нужно) и загружать соответствующий .so.

Comment: @woesss 1. Вариант с заданием разных имен файлов в res/values/strings.xml и res/values-v18/strings.xml и ссылкой на него по имени параметра в AndroidManifest.xml рабочий, да. 2. За потенциальную проблему с OpenGL ES3 тоже спасибо, в итоге сделал через загрузку второго файла (с перехватом исключения и загрузкой первого файла в этом случае) в классе-наследнике от NativeActivity.

Comment: Пожалуйста, только загружать библиотеку ради того чтобы словить исключение как-то не очень решение, тем более это будет происходить на старых слабеньких устройствах. Я думаю, лучше в java-коде проверить версию: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl#version-check , чуть выше ещё написано про AEP и сжатие текстур

Comment: Перегружаете Application, там проверяете версию OpenGL и загружаете соотвествующую библиотеку.